# Need to integrate QuickBooks mac version with my Asp.Net Web Application someone please guide me the steps and how I can achieve it

Tags: macos, quickbooks

Need to integrate QuickBooks mac version with my Asp.Net Web Application someone please guide me the steps and how I can achieve it. The main functionality I need to add the invoice into QuickBooks db(files) when its is generated in my system and if updated status should revert in system back and update the status of that invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBooks for Mac *does not support* any sort of integration or API.

You will need to use QuickBooks for Windows or QuickBooks Online instead.